# How to separate header/footer and data in listview?

Tags: android

my app needs to display data in a list, I walked through some tutorials and figured out to use a header.xml and row.xml. It works fine but now I would like to add more stuff on my header.xml and I found out that the entire header.xml is scrolling with the row.xml as well, which I dont really want. 
Any solution that doesn't require me to rewrite and change my code style completely?

Activity:

public class HistoryActivity extends ListActivity
{

```
private static final String TAG = "HistoryActivity";
ListView lv;
SimpleAdapter sd;

RecordDAO dao = new RecordDAO(HistoryActivity.this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    lv = getListView();
    lv.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.header, null, false));


}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    ArrayList<Record> Records = new ArrayList<Record>();
    Records = (ArrayList<Record>) dao.findAll();


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    for (int x = Records.size()-1; x >=0; x--)
    {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(....// all my data 

        aList.add(map);
    }

    sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, aList, R.layout.row,
            new String[]
            { "date", "name", "time",
                    "rating" }, new int[]              
            { R.id.date, R.id.name, R.id.time,
                     R.id.rating});


    lv.setAdapter(sd);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3)
        {
            TextView tx = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            String s = tx.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(HistoryActivity.this, EditRecordActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("date", s);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

private void insertNewRecord()
{
    dao.add(newRecord);
}
```

}

header.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="4dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Rating"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Rating"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ListActivity. I think it is a bad practice. Use a regular Activity. Just insert a ListView with an id "@android:id/list" into header.xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Rating"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

And you can get the list reference by doing:
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: Yes, I did, please look at the onCreate() at Activity

Comment: But do I still need my row.xml?

Comment: Yes. You need it for the simple adapter.

Comment: getlistview() is not available in activity

Comment: oops: it should be ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Header of a ListView means that it will be the first item of your list, but still will scroll with the list itself.

In your case, you can create some kind of layout (similar to header.xml) and place it above the ListView.

1. Instead of `ListActivity`, extend from `Activity`
2. Create a main_layout.xml that define some views and a ListView.

main_layout

```
<include header.xml/>
<listview>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your header and footer views to scroll with your `ListView`, then make sure that you use the `addHeaderView()` and `addFooterView()` BEFORE you call your `setAdapter()` method.  I would recommend moving the `setAdapter()` method to your `onCreate()` method.